# Any plugin for send message in phoneGap 1.4.1

Tags: ios5, cordova, plugins, sms

I have made one mobile application using PhoneGap.
I have use PhoneGap 1.4.1 version.

In my application, I want to send message on some mobile no.

If any plugins is available, then pls tell me...
and if available then how to use this in ios?

Can we possible this without open native message composer?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a solution to your problem. 
All information is provided on the page below:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/SMSComposer

Kind regards,
Mike